# Storing image in dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo

How to add an image to Dojo datagrid columns?

I have different css classes for different images. How to make it display in datagrid?
How to store image in datastore?

Answer (score 4):

I would try with a formatter in the layout structure:

```
var layout = [
   {
       field: 'image', name: ' ', 
       width: 'auto', formatter: function(value) { 
           var src = imageURL; 
           return "<img src=\"" + src + "\" />"; 
       } 
    }];
```