# Dojo DataGrid inserting image based on JSON Data

Tags: json, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

My JSON data is as follows :

```
"items": [
{
    "batch": "sectionA",
    "full": "N",
    "numStudents": 2,
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "married": "Y"

        },
        {
            "name": "Mary",
            "married": "N"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "batch": "sectionB",
    "full": "Y",
    "numStudents": 3,
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "John",
            "married": "Y"

        },
        {
            "name": "Mary",
            "married": "N"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "married": "N"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I iterate over this JSON and create a DataGrid where : item[].batch is the Header column.
And the item[].students[].name are the rows under the column. This JSON will result in a DataGrid with 2 header columns and 3 rows. Column 1 ("SectionA") will have only two cells underneath it populated. Column 2 ("SectionB") with have 3 cells under it populated.

I can display this in a grid without any issues. But i need to add logic where if : item[].students[].married = "Y" then i have to display a small image next to the Student Name in the cell.

Similarly, if item[].full = "Y" then i have to show the header column in a different color.

Any suggestions ? This has been chewing my brain lately

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this thread: [How to add button or images to dojo grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280149/how-to-add-button-or-images-to-dojo-grid)

and

[Storing image in dojo datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316050/storing-image-in-dojo-datagrid)

It can help to solve your Prolem i guess.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have handled images in a dojo datagrid by altering the structure used for the grid.  Something like the snippet below.  This also allows you to size the grid column to the size of the image file you are using.

```
var marryflag;

(function() {
mygrid.list.structure = [    
{
   cells: [
              [
                {name: 'Married', width: '17%', field: "married",hidden: true,
                    formatter: function(inValue) {
                        marryflag = inValue;
                    } // end formatter function
                },
                {name: 'Name', width: '20px', field: "name",                        
                    formatter: function(inValue) {
                        this.customStyles.push("vertical-align:middle");
                        return "<img src=\"/url_path_to_image/" + inValue + "\" alt=\"" + inValue + "\" width=\"16px\" height=\"16px\" style=\"vertical-align: middle\" /> ";                           
                    }                       
                }
              ]
           ]
      }                                                                                                                                                                
];
})();
```